# What does `Range.Hyperlink.Shape` do?

Tags: excel, vba

I understand, that `Shape.Hyperlink` is the hyperlink associated with the shape and `Shape.Hyperlink.Follow` opens and displays the hyperlink in a web browser, the same as if I left-clicked on the shape.

Q: But what does the `Range.Hyperlink.Shape` do, when I assign some shape to it?

It seems to be a shape associated with the hyperlink....

Does it popup the Shape when I hover over the text of the hyperlink, or something else ?

*For Gary's*:

```
Sub DummySub(rng As Range, shp As Shape)               
   rng.Hyperlinks.Add rng, "http://microsoft.com", "", "Hint"
   rng.Hyperlinks(1).Shape = shp 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please update your question with several lines of code illustrating the usage of the term.

Comment: `Range.Hyperlink.Shape` does not exist.

Comment: @Storax: According to Microsoft it does, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.shape

Comment: I am referring to `Range.Hyperlink.Shape` and this does not exist. This [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hyperlinks) does exist. One has to be precise, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sheet shape you can add a `Link`. Right clicking it or in VBA code. You can choose between `Existing file or web Page`, `Place in this Document`, `Create new Document` or `E-mail-Address`.

It becomes a hyperlink if you choose 'Existing file or web Page` and supply it a web page address.

But `Range.Hyperlink.Shape` does not have a meaning in VBA, I'm afraid...

The `Hyperlink` Range property does not exist in VBA. Only `Hyperlinks`. `Hyperlink.Shape` yes...

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testRangeHiperlynk()
  Dim HypShape As Shape

    Set HypShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 300, 160, 100, 20)
      HypShape.Name = "testRect"
    HypShape.TextFrame.Characters.text = "Go to Google"
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.aDD Anchor:=HypShape, address:="http://www.google.com", SubAddress:="GoToGoogle!A1"
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes("testRect").Hyperlink.Shape.Name
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("testRect").Hyperlink.Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

It creates a rectangle, names it "textRect", writes something on it and then creates a (kind of) hyperlink in A1, but with reference to the newly created shape, targeting `Google.com`.

Then see what `HypShape.Hyperlink.Shape.Name` returns in Immediate window and how the shape defined using `Hyperlink.Shape.Fill` has been colored...

But `Range.Hyperlink.Shape` does not exist in VBA :)

Edited: The property can be used a little cleverer. Run this code (after the first one) and you will be able to set a shape based on the worksheet hyperlinks:

```
Sub testHypShape()
 Dim H As Hyperlink, sh As Shape
  For Each H In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    If H.Shape.Name = "testRect" Then Set sh = H.Shape: Exit For
  Next
  sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 225, 225)
End Sub
```

Comment: So `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Hyperlinks(1).Shape` can exist, but `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Shape` cannot exist.  Weird!  Do you think this question deserves an upvote?

Comment: @George Robinson: I think it does... :)  I had to use my single neuron to prove something I never used in the past. I adapted the answer with a little cleverer use of the property... But should I understand that my answer does not deserve an up vote, too...? :)